# oFx: initialising class instance with mouseEvent

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access, openframeworks

If I run this Code it gives me a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

in `topNav.h` file:

```
 vector<indicatorButton> indicators;
```

and in the `topNav.cpp` file

```
void topNav::setup(ofVec2f p, int n , int *appState) {

// ... other vars here
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= quantityOfPages ; i++){
        indicators[i-1].setup(i, ofVec2f(padding.x + spacing * i, padding.y ), appState );
    }



}
```

and in the indicatorButton.cpp file:

```
indicatorButton::indicatorButton() {
    bRegisteredEvents = false;
}

void indicatorButton::setup(int i, ofVec2f p, int *appState) {

    // this will enable our circle class to listen to the mouse events.
    if(!bRegisteredEvents) {
        ofRegisterMouseEvents(this);
        bRegisteredEvents = true;
    }

   // other variables...blah blah. 


}
```

If I remove the `ofRegisterMouseEvents()` it runs fine. except I don't register the mouse events :/

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers!
Needed to change this:

```
 vector<indicatorButton> indicators;
```

to this

```
 vector<indicatorButton *> indicators;
```